# How to include an image in leaflet as the background job

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I am using class library `leaflet.js` to implement a web page. I want to include an image for base layer, using  `L.tileLayer`. This is what I found in example code.

```
 var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
          'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
           maxZoom: 18
          }
```

Instead of using a sub-domain image how can I include my own image. (or how can I include my image in a sub-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`L.tileLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer) is for a Tile Source (basically, could be a folder with thousands of image parts, each corresponding to a portion of your high resolution image, with different zoom levels).

If you have a single high resolution image that you could not (or do not want to) cut into thousand tiles, you should rather use [`L.imageOverlay()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay)